# reduceByKeyAndWindow in spark2 dataframes

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

In Spark 1.6 with `StreamingContext` I could use function `reduceByKeyAndWindow`

```
        events
            .mapToPair(x-> new Tuple2<String,MyPojo>(x.getID(),x))
            .reduceByKeyAndWindow((a, b) -> 
                     a.getQuality() > b.getQuality() ? a : b
                , Durations.seconds(properties.getWindowLenght()), 
                  Durations.seconds(properties.getSlidingWindow()))
            .map(y->y._2);
```

Now i'm trying to reproduce this logic with spark 2.0.2 and Dataframes. I was able to reproduce the missing function reduceByKey but without window

```
        events
            .groupByKey(x-> x.getID() ,Encoders.STRING())
            .reduceGroups((a,b)-> a.getQuality()>=b.getQuality() ? a : b)
            .map(x->x._2, Encoders.bean(MyPojo.class))
```

I was able to implement window with `groupBy`

```
        events
            .groupBy(functions.window(col("timeStamp"), "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),col("id"))
            .max("quality")
            .join(events, "id");
```

When i used groupBy i got only two columns out of 15 so i tried to get them back with join, but then i got excpetion: `join between two streaming DataFrames/Datasets is not supported;`

Is there any way for me to reproduce logic of `reduceByKeyAndWindow` in spark 2?